# Android data binding error?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I tried to use the *me.tatarka.bindingcollectionadapter:bindingcollectionadapter* library after I added it to gradle :

```
compile 'me.tatarka.bindingcollectionadapter:bindingcollectionadapter:1.3.0'
compile 'me.tatarka.bindingcollectionadapter:bindingcollectionadapter-recyclerview:1.3.0'
```

I used it in the xml file like this:

```
<layout>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    >
    <data>
        <variable name="viewModel" type="com.example.ViewModel"/>
        <import type="me.tatarka.bindingcollectionadapter.LayoutManagers" />
    </data>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/recycler"
        app:layoutManager="@{LayoutManagers.linear()}"

        app:items="@{viewModel.items}"
        app:itemView="@{viewModel.itemView}"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</layout>



  Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. LayoutManagers is missing it file
    ****\ data binding error ****
```

Could someone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Data must be a children of layout

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable name="viewModel" type="com.example.ViewModel"/>
        <import type="me.tatarka.bindingcollectionadapter.LayoutManagers" />
    </data>

   <!-- Rest of your layout -->
</layout>
```